# How can an UWB signal (pulse) radiate from an antenna?

Tags: modulation

This picture compares an uwb- and narrowband-signal:
https://cdn.sewio.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/UWB-e1486395802254.jpg

Like I understand UWB, the signal("pulse") is directly put into the antenna. Using traditional modulation like AM, the amplitude/frequency pr phase of a sinusoidal signal would be changed according to the data signal. Such a signal then can easily radiate from an antenna (dipole) that is around half the wavelength of the carrier.

How can such an impulse "uwb-pulse" radiate from an uwb-antenna? There is no carrier that is modulated?

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. A narrow pulse is still baseband. It needs to be upconverted to the desired center frequency just like any other signal.

Comment: To expand on my comment, here's a scenario. Consider a square pulse with duration 1 ns. Its bandwidth is, say, 3 GHz (2nd harmonic). Connected to an antenna with resonant frequency 1 GHz and BW of 500 MHZ, the pulse will generate energy in that band without needing a modulator. Is this what you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Well, quite easily: A short impulse has a very wide spectrum, which means it contains large ranges of frequencies with significant power.

If you thus take a current impulse and put it to an antenna that can radiate a subset of these frequencies, it will radiate these.

This implicitly happens at every spark gap (the gap and supporting conductors forming kind of a badly-defined antenna). That's exactly what Heinrich Hertz used to prove the existence of electromagnetic waves, 1886.

In that sense, UWB produced through an impulse is the oldest intentional radio transmission.

> here is no carrier that is modulated?

You could say that, but "modulating a carrier" is not the only way to get RF, as the pulse spectrum very well illustrates.

Same works directly and intentionally, too: If I take a 14 GS/s DAC (like the one in the arbitrary waveform generator at our university lab), and feed in pseudorandom numbers that were uncorrelated before I put them through a digital bandpass filter letting through 1 to 6 GHz, I get pretty much an UWB signal too. No explicit carrier involved.

Answer (score 1):

UWB is still a radio technology; it still takes a pulse and modulates it by a carrier.

I'm not finding a definitive guide to the high:low frequency ratio, but if [this Wikipedia table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-wideband#Products) is anything to go by, it's in the range of 3:2, with an outlier at 2:1.  That's well within wideband antenna technology (i.e. log-periodic antennas).

So the actual antenna part of the equation is quite solvable.